# Fill input of type text and press submit using python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this html:

```
<input type="text" class="txtSearch">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="sbtSearch">
```

What I need is to write in the text field and then click on submit using python. The input tags are not inside **Form**. How I could do that?

Comment: I tried to find on google but didn't find any simple example... all i could find is long documentations that I couldnt understand at all... I think that I need to use Mechanize but it need Forms... What I should show you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You shouldn't have to actually populate the fields and 'click' submit. You can simulate the submission and get the desired results.

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and urllib alongside firebug in Firefox. Watch the network traffic with firebug, and get the post parameters from the HTTP POST that the submit is doing. Create a dict and url-encode it. Pass it alongside your url request.

For example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

post_params = {
    param1 : val1,
    param2 : val2,
    param3 : val3
        }
post_args = urllib.urlencode(post_params)

url = 'http://www.website.com/'
fp = urllib.urlopen(url, post_args)
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
```

The parameter `vals` will change according to what you're attempting to submit. Make appropriate accommodations in your code.

Comment: You might consider updating your post to include Python 3.

Comment: urllib is outdated. Use `from lxml import html`

Comment: I think you mean BeautifulSoup...Which, bs4 supports using the lxml html parser, so I'm not quite sure what you're getting at with your comment. In fact, if you have lxml installed in the same environment it becomes the default parser according to the documentation.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a selenium solution if you actually need to populate the fields.  You would typically only need this for testing purposes, though.

```
from selenium import webdriver

webpage = r"https://www.yourwebsite.com/" # edit me
searchterm = "Hurricane Sandy" # edit me

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(webpage)

sbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("txtSearch")
sbox.send_keys(searchterm)

submit = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sbtSearch")
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED** 2019 answer. This code also takes care of the `HTTP 403 Forbidden` errors.

```
import urllib.request as urlRequest
import urllib.parse as urlParse

url = "https://yoururl.com"
values = {"name": "value"}

# pretend to be a chrome 47 browser on a windows 10 machine
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}

# encode values for the url
params = urlParse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")

# create the url
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url=url, data=params, headers=headers)

# open the url
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)

# read the response
respone = x.read()
print(respone)
```

Comment: error message: 
File "/home/path to the file/forUNReports.py", line 17, in <module>
    x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)
.....
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Temporarily

Comment: @sangharsh It probably has to do with the cookies of the page you're trying to read. Check this out https://www.teamfortress.tv/13900/python-urllib2-help#5